# Reg. SiteMap file for my blog

Tags: seo, sitemap

I rolled down my own blog and just wondering what are the rules I've to follow a proper sitemap file for my blog. Do I want to update the sitemap file frequently on adding new articles. Can anyone please share a good link about these sitemaps not much aware of it and how it affects SEO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide a sitemap for SEO, you'll want to make an XML sitemap.

The format is specified on [sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html), and it provides information about how to notify search engines about updates to it.

In general you want the sitemap to be as up-to-date as possible, so as much of your content can be found as possible.

It also gives you the possibility of specifying how often content is changed, as to ensure that the robots will scan the correct pages, and not waste time or bandwidth scanning pages you know will be static. This'll help keep their index of your page as recent as possible.